# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest - "Name or service not known"

Tags: powershell, recursion, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifactory

I have a script that does the following:

- Invoke-WebRequest to recursively search through a specific JFrog Artifactory URL for all *.jar and *.pom files
- Invoke-WebRequest to then download the files when they are found
- All of this in an Azure DevOps Pipeline

this has worked for months, but all of a sudden it's giving me this error:
[image]

You can find a bit of the code here:

```
function CallFor
{
    param ($url)

    $data = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $Headers -SkipCertificateCheck

    $data.Links.Where(
        { $_.href -ne "../" -and $_.href -ne "maven-metadata.xml" -and $($_.href -notlike "*.pom*" -or $_.href -cnotlike "*.jar*") }
    ).ForEach(
        {
            Write-Host "$($url + $_.href)"
            CallFor "$($url + $_.href)"
        }
    )

    $data.Links.Where(
        { 
            $_.href.EndsWith(".pom") -or $_.href.EndsWith(".jar") -and $($($_.href -cnotlike '*RC*') -and $($_.href -cnotlike '*M*') -and $($_.href -cnotlike '*pltf*'))
        }
    ).ForEach(
        {
            Download_Artifact "$($url + $_.href)"
        }
    )
}

...

# MAIN CODE

...

$data = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $Headers -SkipCertificateCheck -UseBasicParsing

$data.Links.Where(
    { 
        $_.href -ne "../" -and $_.href -ne "maven-metadata.xml"
    }
).ForEach(
    {
        CallFor "$($url + $_.href)"
    }
)
```

The error is thrown at random, sometimes it's after 20 seconds, sometimes after 8 minutes, what could be the problem here?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/recommendation-renew-expiring-service-principal-credential?force_isolation=true

Comment: I don't have permissions on my Azure Portal to do that, this is just a random script I made to help with dependencies, I customized my headers with a "Username:Password" pair in Base64. Again, the script has worked for months and only now I've been getting this error.

Comment: Most likely it is caused by a timeout issue.  It could be any place in the network.  Often it is due to checking of credentials with a proxy server.  20 seconds is usually the proxy.  When it is 8 minutes it do to a connection be lost.  Yo umay have hardware issue and checking IP may give clue. I like running long pings to check for errors with ping -t -l 65500 HostName

Comment: You haven’t shared the url (perhaps it’s sensitive), but is it possible the server is no longer available? Have you tried the url from your machine to confirm if it works there?

Comment: It is sensitive, and yes I have tried from my machine and it works, no problem. Again, it happens at random moments, I have no clue what could be the cause, I wonder if I can download the file in a better way, maybe without making a web request but with a maven command (but I guess I would have to create a specific settings.xml then).